# Javascript Foreach for date format prints the same date

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6, momentjs

Good day everyone,

I'm trying to convert the dates from my api using `moment.js` From my api, I have this kind of sample collection

I'm getting the same date like `2019-12-13` in all my dates.

Note: The problem is not in moment since it is working fine in my other codes. Just the `forEach` and I don't know which causes the problem.

```js
const response = {
  data: [{
      'from': '2019-12-31T00:00:00',
      'to': '2020-12-31T00:00:00'
    },
    {
      'from': '2021-12-31T00:00:00',
      'to': '2022-12-31T00:00:00'
    },
    {
      'from': '2023-12-31T00:00:00',
      'to': '2024-12-31T00:00:00'
    }
  ]
}



response.data.forEach((d) => {
  d.from = moment(response.data.from).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
  d.to = moment(response.data.to).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
})

console.log(response.data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're not using `d` in your `moment` calculation. `moment(d.from).format("YYYY-MM-DD")` perhaps? But I'm not sure how `response.data.from` can return `2019-12-13`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: `response.data.from` is `undefined`, which is why `moment()` uses the current time and date. I guess you want `response.data = response.data.map(d => ({ from: moment(d.from).format(...), ... }));`

Comment: after changing something like this `moment(d.from).format("YYYY-MM-DD")` the format doesn't work in view

Comment: This does what it is instructed to do: `response.data.forEach((d) => {
  d.from = moment(d.from).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  d.to = moment(d.to).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
})`

Comment: This question isn't really about momentjs or dates. (or views of some unspecified backend / frontend.) It's about changing array elements, and properly accessing them. As far as I can tell, the question has been answered, and should be closed like @mplungjan suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using `d` in your `forEach` loop - use `d.to` and `d.from` not `response.data.to` and `response.data.from`:

```
response.data.forEach((d)=>{
   d.from = moment(d.from).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
   d.to= moment(d.to).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
});
```

Comment: Typo-close perhaps?

Comment: No, because it's an actual misunderstanding of how to modify the array correctly.

Comment: `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced` after implementing the comment under the question

Comment: It works fine now @JackBashford

Comment: No problem @AppleCiderYummy, always glad to help.